# How to use a variable for multiple event handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I would like to set a variable for one event handler but read it from another one.

Simply something like this:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".notice", function() {
    var notice = 'You have just clicked this item.';
});
$('#save_comment').click(function() {
    alert(notice);
});
```

This code causes the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: notice is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var notice` to `notice`, otherwise it just has scope within the function which defines it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```js
var notice;
$(document.body).on("click", ".notice", function() {
    notice = 'You have just clicked this item.';
});
$('#save_comment').click(function() {
    alert(notice);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="notice">notice</div>
<div id="save_comment">save comment</div>
```

click to **save comment** will set notice to undefined
giving value after **click notice**

Answer (score 0):

Then make it global:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".notice", function() {
    notice = 'You have just clicked this item.';
});
$('#save_comment').click(function() {
    alert(notice);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your situation you might be able to do something like this to avoid making global variables.

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".notice", function() {
    var notice = 'You have just clicked this item.';

  $('#save_comment').data('notice',notice);
});

$('#save_comment').click(function() {
    alert($(this).data('notice'));
});
```